How can I call org-insert-subheading, using the current line as its heading?
I find that org-insert-heading works; it uses the current line as the title.
I find that org-insert-subheading does not work. It insert a blank title, below the current line.

The doc string of org-insert-heading says: ... When at the beginning of a regular line of text, turn it into a heading. - does that not work?

Sorry, I meant org-insert-subheading;)

Write a function that does org-insert-heading first and then does org-do-demote. That's essentially what org-insert-subheading does, except that it does a forward-char in the case you are interested in, which you most definitely don't want it to do.

ok, this works, but it also seems to remove all blank lines above it. It actually deletes all blank lines above it

Can't reproduce that, not even with emacs -Q. Must be some setting of yours.
